# Indexing strsplit() with dplyr()

Tags: r, dplyr

Continuing on my quest to try and do everything I can do in base R within the tidyverse. I want to split a string variable within a dataset, extract an element of the resulting vector and insert that into a second variable in the same  dataset.

I can do this easy enough in base R

```
df <- data.frame(specCond = paste0("cond_",c("cancer", "anxiety", "gastro"), "_", rep(letters[1:3], times = 3)), stringsAsFactors = F)
df$genCond <- sapply(df$specCond, function (i) strsplit(i, "_")[[1]][2])
df

# output
          specCond genCond
# 1  cond_cancer_a  cancer
# 2 cond_anxiety_b anxiety
# 3  cond_gastro_c  gastro
# 4  cond_cancer_a  cancer
# 5 cond_anxiety_b anxiety
# 6  cond_gastro_c  gastro
# 7  cond_cancer_a  cancer
# 8 cond_anxiety_b anxiety
# 9  cond_gastro_c  gastro
```

But when I try to do a similar thing using `mutate()` in `dplyr()` it doesn't work.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- data.frame(specCond = paste0("cond_",c("cancer", "anxiety", "gastro"), "_", rep(letters[1:3], times = 3)), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
       mutate(genCond = strsplit(specCond, "_")[[1]][2]) 
df2

#         specCond genCond
# 1  cond_cancer_a  cancer
# 2 cond_anxiety_b  cancer
# 3  cond_gastro_c  cancer
# 4  cond_cancer_a  cancer
# 5 cond_anxiety_b  cancer
# 6  cond_gastro_c  cancer
# 7  cond_cancer_a  cancer
# 8 cond_anxiety_b  cancer
# 9  cond_gastro_c  cancer
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `sapply` is a loop, you need another loop in `mutate` to go through each `specCond`, split and select second element. You could use `purrr::map_chr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(genCond = purrr::map_chr(specCond, ~strsplit(., "_")[[1]][2]))


#        specCond genCond
#1  cond_cancer_a  cancer
#2 cond_anxiety_b anxiety
#3  cond_gastro_c  gastro
#4  cond_cancer_a  cancer
#5 cond_anxiety_b anxiety
#6  cond_gastro_c  gastro
#7  cond_cancer_a  cancer
#8 cond_anxiety_b anxiety
#9  cond_gastro_c  gastro
```

Or add `rowwise` which does this for each row by default (this might be slow though)

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(genCond = strsplit(specCond, "_")[[1]][2])
```

---

Another way could be to use `tidyr::extract` to get a word between underscores.

```
tidyr::extract(df, specCond, "genCond", regex = ".*_(.*)_.*", remove = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you @ Ronak Shah, A veritable feast of options! Love `rowwise()` I have to check out `purrr`, heard a lot about it.

Comment: I don't think you need to call `strsplit` for every row, as both options seem to do. The default `map` is also to extract values like `[`, so you can do: `df %>% mutate(genCond = map_chr(strsplit(specCond, "_"), 2))`

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me (using `sub` instead of `strsplit`):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(genCond = sub("^cond_([a-z]*)_[a-c]{1}$", "\\1", specCond))
```

Comment: Clever. I''m with you up until the `_[a-c]{1}` part of your regex. What does that do?

Comment: That's just saying that the end of the string ends in "_a", "_b", or "_c"

Comment: What about the `{1}` @Brigadeiro?

Comment: It's saying there's only 1 a, b, or c (not an, ba, abc, etc )